# How to implement socket,io on my Express, Mongoose and EJS app for real time messages?

Tags: express, mongoose, socket.io, ejs, real-time

I am trying to create a chatroom application by using `ExpressJs`, `Mongoose`, `Socket.io` and `Ejs`. So far I have managed to build the functionalities like create a room and add the participants, List all the rooms based on the users that are participants, send messages to a specific chatroom and get all the messages based on the specific chat room. The problem is that I am trying to make this application a real time application with `socket.io`.
So far I have done:

**Room.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const roomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
  participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});

const Room = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);

module.exports = Room;
```

**roomMessage.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const roomMessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  roomId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room' },
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  message: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  sender: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

const RoomMessage = mongoose.model('RoomMessage', roomMessageSchema);

module.exports = RoomMessage;
```

**index.js**

```
//Create our express and socket.io servers
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
// const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const {v4: uuidV4} = require('uuid')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
// const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');

const User = require('./model/User');
const Room = require('./model/Room');
const RoomMessage = require('./model/roomMessage');

// DB Connection
const connectDB = require('./db/db');
const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('./middleware/authMiddleware');

const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
require('./config/passport')(passport);


// Import socket.io library
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

// Create socket.io instance
const io = new Server();

// EJS
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs') // Tell Express we are using EJS
app.use(express.static('public')) // Tell express to pull the client script from the public folder
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'))
// If they join the base link, generate a random UUID and send them to a new room with said UUID

// Express body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Express session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  name: 'sid',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  store: MongoStore.create({mongoUrl: 'mongodb+srv://klitiii:Data01@cluster0.4uaycxy.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'}),
  // cookie: {
  //     path: '/',
  //     httpOnly: true,
  //     secure: true,
  //     sameSite: 'none',
  // }
}))

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

// Routes
// app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/publicRoutes'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/userRoute'));
app.use('/room', require('./routes/roomRoute'));

app.get('/socket.io/socket.io.js', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js');
});

// Set up routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});


// app.get('/videochat', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
//     res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
// })
// // If they join a specific room, then render that room
// app.get('/:room', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
//     const userId = req.user.id
//     res.render('room', {roomId: req.params.room, userId: userId})
//     console.log('a user connected', userId);
// })
// // When someone connects to the server
// io.on('connection', socket => {
//     // When someone attempts to join the room
//     socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
//         socket.join(roomId)  // Join the room
//         socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId) // Tell everyone else in the room that we joined
        
//         // Communicate the disconnection
//         socket.on('disconnect', () => {
//             socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
//         });
//         socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
//             console.log('message: ' + msg);
//             io.emit('chat message', msg);
//           });
//           // console.log('a user connected', userId);
//     })

// })

// const socket = io();
// app.set('socket', socket);

// GET /chat route
// app.get('/chat', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
//   const currentUser = req.user;

//   // Get the list of users from the database
//   User.find({}, (err, users) => {
//     if (err) {
//       console.log(err);
//       return res.sendStatus(500);
//     }

//     // Find the rooms where the current user is a participant
//     Room.find({ participants: req.user._id }, (err, rooms) => {
//       if (err) {
//         console.log(err);
//         return res.sendStatus(500);
//       }

//       // Render the room template with the users and rooms data
//       res.render('chat', { currentUser, users, rooms });
//     });
//   });
// });

// app.get('/chat', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
//   const currentUser = req.user;

//   // Get the list of users from the database
//   User.find({}, (err, users) => {
//     if (err) {
//       console.log(err);
//       return res.sendStatus(500);
//     }

//     // Find the rooms where the current user is a participant
//     Room.find({ participants: req.user._id }, (err, rooms) => {
//       if (err) {
//         console.log(err);
//         return res.sendStatus(500);
//       }

//       // Fetch the chat messages for the current user or selected room
//       RoomMessage.find({ roomId: { $in: rooms.map(room => room._id) } })
//         .populate('sender', 'username') // Populate the sender's username
//         .exec((err, messages) => {
//           if (err) {
//             console.error(err);
//             res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
//             return;
//           }

//           // Determine the selected room based on your logic
//           const selectedRoom = rooms[0]; // For example, selecting the first room in the list

//           // Render the room template with the users, rooms, messages, and selectedRoom data
//           res.render('chat', { currentUser, users, rooms, messages, selectedRoom });
//         });
//     });
//   });
// });


app.get('/chat', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const currentUser = req.user;

  // Get the list of users from the database
  app.get('/chat', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    const currentUser = req.user;
  
    // Get the list of users from the database
    User.find({}, (err, users) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }
  
      // Find the rooms where the current user is a participant
      Room.find({ participants: req.user._id }, (err, rooms) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
  
        // Fetch the chat messages for the current user or selected room
        RoomMessage.find({ roomId: { $in: rooms.map(room => room._id) } })
          .populate('sender', 'username') // Populate the sender's username
          .exec((err, messages) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
              return;
            }
  
            // Sort the rooms based on the date and time of the last message sent by the other participant
            rooms.sort((a, b) => {
              const lastMessageA = messages.find(message => message.roomId.toString() === a._id.toString());
              const lastMessageB = messages.find(message => message.roomId.toString() === b._id.toString());
  
              if (!lastMessageA && !lastMessageB) {
                return 0;
              }
  
              if (!lastMessageA) {
                return 1;
              }
  
              if (!lastMessageB) {
                return -1;
              }
  
              return lastMessageB.createdAt - lastMessageA.createdAt;
            });
  
            // Determine the selected room based on your logic
            const selectedRoom = rooms[0]; // For example, selecting the first room in the sorted list
  
            // Render the room template with the users, rooms, messages, and selectedRoom data
            res.render('chat', { currentUser, users, rooms, messages, selectedRoom });
          });
      });
    });
  });
  });

// GET /chat/:roomId route
app.get('/chat/:roomId', (req, res) => {
  const currentUser = req.user; // Assuming you have implemented user authentication
  const roomId = req.params.roomId;

  // Find the rooms where the current user is a participant
  Room.find({ participants: currentUser._id }).exec((err, rooms) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      return;
    }

    // Find the selected room
    const selectedRoom = rooms.find(room => room._id.toString() === roomId);

    if (!selectedRoom) {
      // No room selected, display an error message or redirect
      res.status(404).send('Room not found');
      return;
    }

    // Get the chat messages for the selected room
    RoomMessage.find({ roomId })
      .populate('sender', 'username') // Populate the sender's username
      .sort({ createdAt: 1 }) // Sort the messages based on the date and time (ascending order)
      .exec((err, messages) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
          return;
        }

        // Fetch the list of users
        User.find({}, (err, users) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
            return;
          }
          res.render('chat', { rooms, messages, currentUser, selectedRoom, users });
        });
      });
  });
});

// Socket.io connection event
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('User connected:', socket.id);

  // Join a room
  socket.on('joinRoom', roomId => {
    socket.join(roomId);
  });

  // Leave a room
  socket.on('leaveRoom', roomId => {
    socket.leave(roomId);
  });

  // Send message
  socket.on('sendMessage', ({ roomId, message }) => {
    // Save the message in the database using RoomMessage model
    const newMessage = new RoomMessage({
      roomId,
      userId: currentUser._id, // Assuming you have the current user available
      message,
      sender: currentUser._id // Assuming you have the current user available
    });

    newMessage.save((err, savedMessage) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        return;
      }

      // Emit the saved message to all participants in the room except the current user
      socket.to(roomId).emit('receiveMessage', { roomId, message: savedMessage });
    });
  });

  // Update room status
  socket.on('updateRoomStatus', ({ roomId, status }) => {
    // Update the room status in the database using Room model

    // Emit the updated room status to all participants in the room
    socket.to(roomId).emit('roomStatusUpdated', { roomId, status });
  });

  // Disconnect event
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected:', socket.id);
    // Perform necessary cleanup or updates related to the disconnected user
  });
});

app.post('/room/:roomId/new-message', (req, res) => {
  const currentUser = req.user; // Assuming you have implemented user authentication
  const roomId = req.params.roomId;
  const content = req.body.content;

  // Create a new message object
  const newMessage = new RoomMessage({
    roomId,
    sender: currentUser._id,
    message: content
  });

  // Save the new message to the database
  newMessage.save((err, savedMessage) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle the error
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      return;
    }

    // Emit the saved message to all participants in the room except the current user
    io.to(roomId).emit('receiveMessage', { roomId, message: savedMessage });

    // Redirect back to the chat room
    res.redirect('/chat/' + roomId);
  });
});

connectDB();


// Start the server
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**chat.ejs**

```
<div class="messaging">
                    <div class="inbox_msg">
                        <div class="inbox_people d-none d-lg-block">
                            <div class="headind_srch">
                              <!-- <div class="recent_heading">
                                <h4>Chatly</h4>
                              </div> -->
                              <div class="srch_bar">
                                <div class="stylish-input-group">
                                  <input type="text" class="search-bar"  placeholder="Search" >
                                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <!-- <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createRoom"><i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i> </a> -->
                                  </span> </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="add_top">
                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createRoom"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></fa-icon> </a>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <% if (rooms.length > 0) { %>
                            <div class="inbox_chat">
                              <!-- List of Rooms -->
                              <% rooms.forEach(function(room) { %>
                                <a href="/chat/<%= room._id %>">
                              <div type="button" class="chat_list  list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                                <div class="chat_people">
                                  <div class="chat_img"> <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil"> </div>
                                  <div class="chat_ib">
                                    <h5><%= room.name %> 
                                      <% const lastMessage = messages.find(message => message.roomId.toString() === room._id.toString()); %>
                                      <% if (lastMessage) { %>
                                        <p>Last Message: <%= lastMessage.message %></p>
                                        <p>Last Message Sender: <%= lastMessage.sender.username %></p>
                                      <% } else { %>
                                        <p>No messages</p>
                                      <% } %>
                                      <!-- <span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span> -->
                                    </h5>
                                    <!-- <p>Test, which is a new approach to have all solutions
                                      astrology under one roof.</p> -->
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </a>
                            <% }) %>

                            <% } else { %>
                              <p>No rooms found.</p>
                            <% } %>
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

<div class="headind_srch">
<div class="recent_heading">
   <a href="contacts.html">
       <span class="d-lg-none d-sm-block d-md-block bacarr"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></span>
   </a> 
  <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" width="40px" height="40px" class="rounded-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  <b style="padding: 0 0 0 15px;"><%= selectedRoom.name %></b>
  <!-- <span id="action_menu_btn"><i class="fas fa-video"></i></span> -->
  <span id="action_menu_btn" style="padding-right: 15px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
  <!-- <span id="action_menu_btn"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span> -->
</div>
<div class="action_menu">
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> View profile</li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Add to close friends</li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add to group</li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-ban"></i> Block</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="mesgs">

<!-- Other HTML code -->
<div class="msg_history" id="mesgsbot">
  <% if (messages && messages.length === 0) { %>
    <div class="right-side-empty"></div>
  <% } else if (messages) { %>
    <% messages.forEach(function(message) { %>
      <% if (message.sender._id.toString() === currentUser._id.toString()) { %>
        <div class="outgoing_msg">
          <div class="sent_msg">
            <p><%= message.message %></p>
            <span class="time_date"><%= message.sender.username %> | <%= message.createdAt.toLocaleDateString() %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% } else { %>
        <div class="incoming_msg">
          <div class="incoming_msg_img">
            <img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png" alt="sunil">
          </div>
          <div class="received_msg">
            <div class="received_withd_msg">
              <p><%= message.message %></p>
              <span class="time_date"><%= message.sender.username %> | <%= message.createdAt.toLocaleDateString() %></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% } %>
    <% }) %>
  <% } %>
</div>


<div class="card-footer">
 <div class="type_msg">
  <div class="input_msg_write">
    <%_ if(typeof selectedRoom !== "undefined"){ _%>
      <form action="/room/<%= selectedRoom._id %>/new-message" method="POST">
      <!-- <form action="/room/<%= selectedRoom._id %>/new-message" method="POST"> -->
        <input class="write_msg" type="text" name="content" placeholder="Type your message" required />
        <button class="msg_send_btn" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane" style="color: #5680e9"></i></button>
      </form>
    <%_ } _%>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Establish socket connection
      const socket = io();
  
      // Join the room
      socket.emit('joinRoom', '<%= selectedRoom._id %>');
  
      // Receive message event
      socket.on('receiveMessage', ({ roomId, message }) => {
        // Display the received message
        const messagesContainer = document.getElementById('messages');
        const newMessage = document.createElement('p');
        newMessage.innerText = message.sender.username + ': ' + message.message;
        messagesContainer.appendChild(newMessage);
      });
  
      // Send message event
      const messageForm = document.getElementById('message-form');
      const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
  
      messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const messageContent = messageInput.value.trim();
        if (messageContent !== '') {
          // Send the message
          socket.emit('sendMessage', { roomId: '<%= selectedRoom._id %>', message: messageContent });
  
          // Clear the input field
          messageInput.value = '';
        }
      });
  
      // Disconnect event
      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Socket disconnected');
        // Perform necessary cleanup or updates related to the disconnected socket
      });
    </script>
```

Right now I want to implement the following:

1. Sort the chatRooms by new unopened date and time.
2. Show the new message to the all participants without refreshing the page.